# Is this space a subset of $L^p(\mathbb R^m)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces, lp-spaces, machine-learning

Let $G_m(\mathbb R^m) := \left\{ g: \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R, g(x) = \langle w_2, \phi(W_1 x + b) \rangle \ \vert \ n < \infty, W_1\in \mathbb R^{n\times m}, w_2, b\in \mathbb R^n\right\}$. Also, the function $\phi$ is given componentwise by $\phi(z) = \left(\phi^{\star}\left(z_i\right)\right)_{i = 1, \dots, n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb R^n$, where $\phi^{\star}: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded and nonconstant.

Now, let us consider the space $L^{p}(\mathbb R^m)$, $1\leq p < \infty$ for a **finite measure $\mu$ on** $\mathbb{R}^m$.

My question would be: My teacher said that $G_m(\mathbb R^m)$ is a linear subspace of $L^p(\mathbb R^m)$, but I have problems proving that $G_m(\mathbb R^m)$ is a subspace of $L^p(\mathbb R^m)$. So let $g\in G_m(\mathbb R^m)$, then we need to show that $\vert\vert g\vert\vert_p = \left( \int_{\mathbb R^m} \vert g\vert^p d\mu \right)^{1/p} = \left( \int_{\mathbb R^m} \vert \langle  w_2, \phi(W_1 x + b)\rangle\vert^p d\mu \right)^{1/p} < \infty$. But how do I prove this?

(The context of this question is Hornik's famous $L^p$ universal approximation result for a feedforward neural network.)

Comment: You need to assume that $\phi$ is measurable. All elements of $G_m$ are bounded, so you can use the inequality $\|u\|_p\leq \mu(\mathbb{R}^m)^{1/p}\|u\|_\infty$.

Comment: 1) What are $\phi$ and $u$ (is it what I call $g$)? Your notation seems to be incosistent. 2) Maybe you can add a reference to the inequality you wrote?

Comment: 1) $\phi$ is in your question, $u$ is just any measurable function. You can apply it to $g\in G_m$. 2) This inequality follows from the elementary properties of the integral (monotonicity and linearity).

Comment: 1) I see your point that we need to assume that $\phi$ is measurable, but is there maybe a way to prove this, given that $\phi^{*}$ is bounded and nonconstant, and that we have a finite measure? 

2) You are right, thanks!

Comment: Boundedness does not help you, there are non-measurable bounded functions.

Comment: This is very strange. Please take a look here: https://web.njit.edu/~usman/courses/cs675_spring20/hornik-nn-1991.pdf

Theorem 1 on page 252 clearly does not state that we need a measurable function $\psi$ (what we called $\phi$), and the proof on page 254f. does not assume measurability either.. But again, I undertand your point..

Comment: Then that's just an oversight/imprecision by the author.

Comment: I am also stuck showing that $G_m(\mathbb R^m)$ is a subspace of $L^p(\mathbb R^m)$, I made a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195015/is-this-subset-a-subspace-of-lp-mathbb-rm

Please feel free to take a brief look.