# Is this subset a subspace of $L^p(\mathbb R^m)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, machine-learning

Let $G_m(\mathbb R^m) := \left\{ g: \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R, g(x) = \langle w_2, \phi(W_1 x + b) \rangle \ \vert \ n < \infty, W_1\in \mathbb R^{n\times m}, w_2, b\in \mathbb R^n\right\}$. Also, the function $\phi$ is given componentwise by $\phi(z) = \left(\phi^{\star}\left(z_i\right)\right)_{i = 1, \dots, n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb R^n$, where $\phi^{\star}: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is bounded and nonconstant.
(The context of this question is Hornik's famous $L^p$ universal approximation result for a feedforward neural network.)

I already convinced myself [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194351/is-this-space-a-subset-of-lp-mathbb-rm) that $G_m(\mathbb R^m)$ is a subset of $L^p(\mathbb R^m)$, $1\leq p< \infty$. What I would now like to show is that $G_m(\mathbb R^m)$ is also a **subspace** of $L^p(\mathbb R^m)$. So:

- $0 \in G_m(\mathbb R^m)$,
- $g\in G_m(\mathbb R^m) \Rightarrow \lambda g\in \mathbb R^m, \lambda\in\mathbb R$.

The only thing missing is showing that if $g_1$, $g_2 \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then also $g_1 - g_2 \in \mathbb R^m$ (i.e., that our subset is closed under subtraction). Let $g_1(x) = \left\langle \tilde{w}_2, \phi\left( \tilde{W}_1 x + \tilde{b} \right)\right\rangle$, $g_2\left(x\right) = \left\langle w_2, \phi\left(W_1 x + b\right)\right\rangle$.

Unfortunately, I cannot use the property $\left\langle u + v, w\right\rangle = \langle u, w\rangle + \langle v, w\rangle$, so I am not sure how to proceed. However, our teacher told us that $G_m(\mathbb R^m)$ **is** a subspace of $L^p$.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Write out explicitly (without inner products and matrices) how the elements of $G_m$ look like. Then it should be easy to get the claim.

Comment: @PhoemueX How exactly am I supposed to get rid of the matrices? So what I have so far: $g_1\left(x\right) - g_2\left(x\right) = \langle \tilde{w}_2, \phi(\tilde{w}_1x + b) \rangle - \langle w_2, \phi(w_2x + b) \rangle = \tilde{w}^{T}_{2}\phi(\tilde{W}_1x + b) - w_2^T\phi(W_2 x + b)$.

Comment: What I meant is that the elements of $G_m$ are precisely the functions of the form $g(x) = \sum_{\ell=1}^n w_\ell \phi(\langle v_\ell, x \rangle + b_\ell)$ where $w_\ell,b_\ell \in \Bbb{R}$ and $v_\ell \in \Bbb{R}^m$. Using this representation, the claim should follow easily.

Comment: May I ask: Would you mind showing a bit more details? There are two things confusing me: (i) Why is the way you wrote it advantageous? After all, $\phi(z)  = \phi^{\star}(z_i)_{i = 1, \dots, n}$ is in general non-linear, (ii) by $v_l$, do you mean the $l$-th row of the weight matrices $W_1$?